# Get all documents from elastic search with a field having same value

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have documents of type Order and they have a field bulkOrderId. Bulkorderid represents a group or bulk of orders issued at once. They all have the same Id like this :

```
Order {

   bulkOrderId": "bulkOrder:12345678";

}
```

The id is unique and is generated using UUID.

How do I find groups of orders with the same bulkOrderId from elasticsearch when the bulkOrderId is not known? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and a [`top_hits` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "bulks": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bulkOrderId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "orders": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still evaluating elasticsearch and learning about it hence one more question. Does elastic give exact search results? E.g. In the above case, will elastic return all the documents for each bulkorderId? Or if I specifically provide a bulkorderId will elastic give exactly the same number of documents every time I fire a search query?

Comment: Yes, though depending on how many documents you have, you might need to increase the size in your top_hits aggregation. If you add a filter for a specific bulkOrderId, then yes, you'll always get the same documents in the response.

Comment: @Val sorry for my question here, I have little bit same problem I want to make search by field name and value, and then after I get it, this data has one field which unique to other data, and I want to get all data with this unique field

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen it's best to ask a new question by explaining your need.